Notation for functions of class $C^m$ that are smooth almost everywhere.
Let $f\colon \Omega \to \mathbb R$ be in $C^m(\Omega)$ and there exists finite many point $\{x_1,\cdots,x_n\}$ in $\Omega$ such that $f \in C^{m'}(\Omega \setminus \cup_{j=1}^{n} S_j)$ where sets $S_j \subset \Omega$ are open neighborhoods around $x_j$, $m$ is a natural number and $m' = \infty$ or $m' >m $ is a natural number. In essence, except for a few troublesome points, function $f$ is more regular in the rest of the domain. For instance $f(x) = x\log{|x|}$ is $C[-1,1]$ and $f|_{[-1,1] \setminus S_0}$ is $C^\infty$ where $S_0$ is a neighborhood around origin. Notice that $f$ is not $C^1_{pw}[-1,1]$, since this requires the limit of the derivative to exist at $0$, which is not satisfied. I am searching for a standard notation for these kind of functions.

I am not aware of any specific notation.  I suspect that something like $C^m$-a.e. would be understood.

Generally speaking, folks working in functional analysis are interested in spaces of functions which have some additional structure, e.g. Banach spaces and Hilbert spaces and whatnot.  The set of functions which are almost everywhere smooth (or $C^m$) are less well-behaved with respect to those kinds of structures.  Some of this can be massaged away by considering equivalence classes of functions (two functions are equivalent if they agree almost everywhere), but this kind of runs against the "usual" goals of studying smooth functions (e.g. classifying solutions to DEs, demonstrating the existence of solutions, etc).
Moreover, the description in the question doesn't quite meet my expectations for what an almost everywhere smooth function would look like—if I were to say that $f$ is $C^m$ almost everywhere, I would expect $f$ to be smooth on some open set $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, where $\mathbb{R}\setminus \Omega$ has measure zero.  Of course, maybe the goal is to avoid all such pathologies, as measure zero sets can still be a problem (e.g. there are dense subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ of measure zero).
Rather, the question seems to define functions which are smooth away from some "small" open set.
As such, I would be surprised to learn that there is a standard notation for "almost everywhere $C^m$ functions" (either the version I give, or the version described in the question).
That being said, the goal of notation is to communicate ideas, and to reduce the number of words required to communicate those ideas.  With a solidly written definition, I would suspect that one could get away with calling this class of functions "$C^m$-a.e.".

I was attempting to generalize the definition of piece wise smooth functions, which requires the limit to be finite at point of discontinuities. I think you are right, calling it "almost everywhere" is not quite what I have written. Inspired form your notation, how about $C^{m}_{as}$, which are almost smooth functions. @Xander
